# How to delete a Spark DataFrame using sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

I have created a Spark dataframe called "iris" using the below

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)
```

now I want to delete the Spark dataframe "iris" (not the dataframe in R) how do I do that?

Comment: `rm(iris)` .....?

Comment: @Tung I want to remove the spark data.frame no the R data.frame.

Answer (score 2):

This strictly depends on what you when say *delete dataframe*. You have to remember that in general, Spark data frames are not the same type of objects as you plain local data structures. Spark `DataFrame` is rather a description than a data container.

`sparklyr` itself, depends primarily on Spark SQL interface. When you call `copy_to` (or any other data import method, it:

- Registers a temporary table.
- With default parameters (which really should be avoided) it eagerly caches the tables.

This means that the natural way to *delete dataframe* is to drop the temporary view (referencing it [by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51867877/6910411) either with `dplyr` / `dbplyr`:

```
db_drop_table(sc, "iris")
```

or Spark's own methods:

```
sc %>% spark_session() %>% invoke("catalog") %>% invoke("dropTempView", "iris")
```

Please note that it will invalidate local bindings, so any attempt to access `iris_tbl` after calling any of the methods shown above will fail:

```
iris_tbl
```

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: iris; line 2 pos 5
...
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'iris' not found in database 'default'
...
```