# How to refer to a Spark DataFrame by name in sparklyr and assign it to a variable?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

Say I ran the following code and I forgot to assign the Spark dataframe `iris` to a variable in R and I can't use `.Last.value` to assign because I had run some other code right after copying the data to Spark.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
copy_to(sc, iris)
2+2 # ran some other code so can't use .Last.value
```

How do I assing the Spark dataframe "iris" to a variable in R called `iris_tbl`?

Answer (score 2):

`copy_to` provides additional `name` argument By default it is set to:

```
deparse(substitute(df))
```

so in your case the name will be `iris`. If you want more predictable behavior you should set the name manually:

```
copy_to(sc, iris, name = "foo")
```

Then you can access it `dplyr` way with `tbl`:

```
dplyr::tbl(sc, "foo")
```

or via Spark session:

```
sc %>% spark_session() %>% invoke("table", "foo") %>% sdf_register()
```

All production ready reader methods (`copy_to` shouldn't be used as anything else than a testing and development tool) require `name`, so you can reference tables the same way

```
spark_read_csv(sc, "bar", path)
tbl(sc, "bar")
```